# QTextEdit refresh after setText()/insertPlainText()

Tags: qt, qt5, qtextedit

I have a QTextEdit widget in a private slot, which I update regularly with setText() and insertPlainText().

I have found that setText()/insertPlainText() does not update the QTextEdit widget immediately.  Instead, the QTextWidget is updated when the slot function returns.  To test this, I have put a sleep() just after the setText()/insertPlainText().

```
class MyWindow : public Widget
{
    MyWindow()
    {
        my_button = new QPushButton(this);
        my_edit   = new QTextEdit(this);

        connect(my_button, 
                &QPushButton::clicked, 
                this, 
                &MyWindow::my_callback);
    }

    private slots:

        void my_callback()
        {
            my_edit->setText("sample text");

            // nothing happens; the QTextEdit 
            // widget does not show "sample text"

            sleep(10); 

            // the QTextEdit widget will show
            // "sample text" AFTER the sleep,
            // when my_callback returns.
         }

    private:
        QPushButton* my_button;
        QTextEdit*   my_edit;
}
```

This is a problem for me because I need to print a message in my QTextEdit widget BEFORE launching a time-consuming process (using QProcess).  Currently, this message is not being printed until after QProcess process has returned.

Does anyone know how I can get the QTextEdit widget to show its contents right after setText()/insertPlainText()?

Using Qt5 on Fedora 29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never execute a task that consumes a lot of time in the GUI thread. In general, the solution is to execute that task in another thread, but in your case it indicates that you use QProcess, so I assume that you are using one of the methods waitForFinished(), waitForStarted() or waitForReadyRead(), instead you should use the signals:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QWidget(parent)
    {
        button.setText("Press me");
        QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout{this};
        lay->addWidget(&button);
        lay->addWidget(&textedit);
        connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::onClicked);
        connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, this, &Widget::onReadyReadStandardError);
        connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &Widget::onReadAllStandardOutput);
    }
private Q_SLOTS:
    void onClicked(){
        textedit.setText("sample text");
        process.start("ping 8.8.8.8");
    }
    void onReadyReadStandardError(){
        textedit.append(process.readAllStandardError());
    }
    void onReadAllStandardOutput(){
        textedit.append(process.readAllStandardOutput());
    }
private:
    QPushButton button;
    QTextEdit textedit;
    QProcess process;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if calling

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents()
```

right after the ->setText("sample text") would do the trick in your case.